# Plot histograms in a loop and show them side by side

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot n number of histograms and show them all together side by side (not in the same histograms.

I have tried this code:

```
for r in range(1, n):
    plt.hist(combined['apple{} tomato'.format(n)], bins = bin, alpha=0.5, color='#0bf9ea')
    plt.hist(combined['apple{} potato'.format(n)], bins =  bin, alpha=0.5, color='#ff7fa7')
    plt.show()
```

When I type this code, it will show me histogram 1, then when I close the figure, histogram 2 will appear and so on until histogram n.

```
for r in range(1, n):
    plt.hist(combined['apple{} tomato'.format(n)], bins = bin, alpha=0.5, color='#0bf9ea')
    plt.hist(combined['apple{} potato'.format(n)], bins =  bin, alpha=0.5, color='#ff7fa7')
plt.show()
```

However, when I try this code, it shows me one histogram with all the histograms in one.

Is there a way to show all n different histograms separately but in one window ?

Thanks :D

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883598/pandas-histogram-df-hist-group-by/45884249#45884249

Comment: Thanks @Brad Solomon, this helped me a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using matplotlib.pyplot.subplot()?

```
 for r in range(1,n): 
    matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(nrows, ncols, r) 
    plt.hist()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
a = plt.subplots(n-1, 2)[1].ravel()

for r in range (1, n):
    a[0].hist(combined['apple{} tomato'.format(n)], bins = bin, alpha=0.5, color='#0bf9ea')
    a[1].hist(combined['apple{} potato'.format(n)], bins =  bin, alpha=0.5, color='#ff7fa7')

plt.show()
```